# "my first rust": the method `unwrap_or_default` exists for enum `Option<&mut ...>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied

Tags: rust, functional-programming

My very first `rust` program/function is supposed to walk a dir tree and deliver a `HashMap` with `K(mime_as_string)` and `V(count_sum, size_sum)`. And I want it in FP style.

So what I have is this:

```rust
fn files_info4(rootpath: &str) {

    struct FTypeStats {
        count: u64,
        size: u64,
    }

    impl Default for FTypeStats {
        fn default() -> Self {
            FTypeStats {
                count: 0,
                size: 0,
            }
        }
    }

    // get file type stats directly/functionally/lazy
    let fts = WalkDir::new(rootpath)
    .min_depth(1)
    .max_depth(99)
    .into_iter()
    .filter_map(|entry| entry.ok())
    .map(|entry| (entry, entry.metadata().map_or(false, |m| m.is_file())))
    .filter(|(e, f)| *f)
    .fold(HashMap::new(), | mut acc: HashMap<String, FTypeStats>, (e, _) | {
        let ftype = tree_magic::from_filepath(e.path());
        acc.get_mut(&ftype).unwrap_or_default().count += 1;
        acc.get_mut(&ftype).unwrap_or_default().size += e.metadata().map_or(0, |m| m.len());
        acc
    });
}
```

where I did the `impl Default` after meeting the error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `unwrap_or_default` exists for enum `Option<&mut FTypeStats>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:54:29
   |
54 |         acc.get_mut(&ftype).unwrap_or_default().count += 1;
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Option<&mut FTypeStats>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&mut FTypeStats: Default`
```

But it still didn't help, i.e. the same error remains.

#### Questions:

1. how to make it compile/run
2. can the evaluation chain be optimised? (And is the code within `fold` actually correct regarding e.g. the assignments I need for `FTypeStats` and initialization for the default/initial values? (It feels a bit "implicit"))

TIA!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems here: First, calling `.get_mut()` on the `HashMap` gives you an `Option` which is `None` in case the key is not in the map. The `Option` itself is detached from the map (aside from lifetime constraints), so in the `None`-case, there is no link back into the map that would put a constructed-from-default value in it's proper place.

Second, as the error message says, the method `unwrap_or_default()` requires the inner type of `Option` to actually implement `Default`, in this case `&mut FTypeStats`. Not only does such an implementation not exist in your code, but it would also be very hard to do so because generating a (valid) mutable reference to some type out of thin air - which is the whole point of `Default` - is practically impossible.

The solution is to use the [`entry()` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) on the `HashMap` instead of `get_mut()`:

```
*acc.entry(&ftype).or_default().count += 1;
```

The call to `entry()` gives you a proxy-value to wherever `&ftype` is - or would be - in the `HashMap`. The call to `or_default()` always gives you a `&mut FTypeStats`. If `&ftype` is not in the map, it uses `Default` on `FTypeStats` (not `Default` on `&mut FTypeStats`) to generate a new entry, inserts it, and gives you a mutable reference to that.

Comment: thanks, that got me much closer, though I now get a new problem: If my hash key is a value (`String`) I get *use of moved value: `ftype`* for the second time I index (for `+size`); if I try to remedy that by using a reference (e.g. `&str`) as key, I get (for both indexing) *`ftype` does not live long enough*. If I try to remedy *that* (naively?) by implementing `add` for `FTypeStats` and adding like this `acc.entry(ftype).or_default().add(FTypeStats{count: 1, size: e.metadata().map_or(0, |m| m.len())});`, it runs but all values are `0`. (And it's much slower than my `go` version)